# Create a pivot table of total births by sex and year and then plot them

Tags: python, pandas, plot, pivot

I want to create a pivot table of total births by sex and year and then plot them.

The .csv data looks like:

```
             name sex  births  year
0         Jessica   F   46459  1990
1          Ashley   F   45544  1990
2        Brittany   F   36532  1990
3          Amanda   F   34391  1990
4        Samantha   F   25864  1990
5           Sarah   F   25803  1990
6       Stephanie   F   24853  1990
7        Jennifer   F   22218  1990
8       Elizabeth   F   20739  1990
9          Lauren   F   20498  1990
10          Megan   F   20249  1990
11          Emily   F   19349  1990
12         Nicole   F   17948  1990
13          Kayla   F   17534  1990
14          Amber   F   15862  1990
15         Rachel   F   15692  1990
16       Courtney   F   15374  1990
17       Danielle   F   14330  1990
18        Heather   F   14216  1990
19        Melissa   F   13996  1990
20        Rebecca   F   13669  1990
21       Michelle   F   13408  1990
22        Tiffany   F   13160  1990
23        Chelsea   F   12782  1990
24      Christina   F   11924  1990
25      Katherine   F   11613  1990
26         Alyssa   F   11259  1990
27        Jasmine   F   11034  1990
28          Laura   F   10903  1990
29         Hannah   F   10276  1990
          ...  ..     ...   ...
587789      Ziyun   M       5  2009
587790     Zlatan   M       5  2009
587791       Zoen   M       5  2009
587792     Zubayr   M       5  2009
587793     Zuhaib   M       5  2009
587794      Zykee   M       5  2009
587795     Zykell   M       5  2009
587796      Zylar   M       5  2009
587797  Zyquarius   M       5  2009
587798      Zyran   M       5  2009
587799    Zyreion   M       5  2009
587800     Zyrian   M       5  2009
587801     Zyvion   M       5  2009
```

Now, with this file, I need to do the task. I need to create the correct pivot table and plot it.

I've tried to do it with the following lines, but it is not correct.

```
data = pd.read_csv('/file.csv',index_col = 'year', parse_dates=True)
print(data)

pivot = data.pivot_table(['births'], index=['sex','year'])

print(pivot)

fig1 = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax1.plot(pivot['births'], linestyle="--", color="k", label="M")
ax1.plot(pivot['births'], linestyle="--", color="b", label="F")

ax1.tick_params(rotation=90)
```

Comment: `pd.pivot_table(index='year', columns='sex', values='births', aggfunc='sum')`?

Comment: how would I plot it so it shows 2 lines (male and female) ?